# Upgrade of spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.0.5 and dependency issues

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, blackduck

The Blackduck scanning report is resulted in one of the high vulnerability.
[image]

The transitive dependency is navigated from org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.0.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar -> finally ends up in netty-codec

Note: I changed the version to spring-boot-starter-webflux - 3.0.5 by adding the dependency

The short term recommendation provided is - upgrade netty-codec to 4.1.90.Final version. I added the netty-codec dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.90.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But , I am getting the error as "Some Enforcer rules have failed. ". The reason is shown in the following tree

```
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.9:compile paths to dependency are:

  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.0.5:compile
    +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.9:compile
```

If any one know the solution to resolve the problem , please help me here

Comment: I tried to simulate and the org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.DependencyConvergence passed. Can you please add enough of your pom file (eg spring-boot-starter-parent) so I can get it to fail?

Comment: This is the information about spring-boot-starter-parent , <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.9</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dependencies in the parent pom need to be overwritten. To do this the `dependencyManagement` tag should be used as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.90.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and the ordinary dependency on io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.90.Final removed.

Of concern is the mixing of spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.9 (Java 11 compatible) with spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.0.5 (not Java 11 compatible - requires Java 17). Are all your prod environments Java 17?. If not you should remove the version 3.0.5 from spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency.

If you have Java 17 environment the upgrade your starter to 3.0.5.

Comment: We are using Java 17 for all the environment. After changing to spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.0, the authentication is not successful and it fails to execute @PreAuthorize etc.

Comment: There's no need to upgrade to 3.0.5 if you are using Java 17 as Spring Boot 2.x supports Java 17.

Comment: If you are using Java 17 everywhere and  spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.0 causes pain then  spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.9 is fine. Did the dependencyManagement suggestion fix the Enforcer failure though?

Comment: Hi John, Yes . DependencyManagement fixed the Enforcer failure. As i already mentioned , we are in a position to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 to avoid the blackduck issues. While upgrading , there are lot of changes in the code and failed in calling the custom AuthenticationProvider of Spring security. 
.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider())

Comment: I believe that I answered your question regarding dependency convergence. Can you please accept the answer?